# Lower bound union of a sorted array and unsorted array

Tags: algorithms, lower-bounds

Suppose given two arrays $A$ and $B$ with length $n$. Array $A$ is sorted and $B$ is unsorted. Is there any lower bound for computing $A\cup B$?

Comment: What is $A \cup B$?

Comment: What is the algorithm allowed to do? That is, what is the computation model? Are you allowing only comparisons?